# Jenkins restart Tomcat

Tags: shell, tomcat, jenkins

I'm trying to restart tomcat after deploy. I wrote shell script

```
PID=$(ps -aux | grep tomcat-7.0.72 | grep java | awk ' { print $2 } ');
cd /var/lib/apache-tomcat-7.0.72/bin
kill -9 $PID
./startup.sh
```

which should kill tomcat process and run startup.sh. After run this job on console I can see

```
Using     JAVA_OPTS: -server -Xms2g -Xmx8g -XX:PermSize=1024m -XX:+UseParallelGC -XX:NewRatio=3 -Djavax.servlet.request.encoding=UTF-8 -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9090 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=192.168.1.30 -Djsse.enableSNIExtension=false
Tomcat started.
Finished: SUCCESS
```

This log shows that everything works correctly but tomcat is not started.
When I run ./startup.sh on console I can see

```
Using     JAVA_OPTS: -server -Xms2g -Xmx8g -XX:PermSize=1024m -XX:+UseParallelGC -XX:NewRatio=3 -Djavax.servlet.request.encoding=UTF-8 -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9090 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=192.168.1.30 -Djsse.enableSNIExtension=false
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /var/lib/apache-tomcat-7.0.72
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /var/lib/apache-tomcat-7.0.72
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /var/lib/apache-tomcat-7.0.72/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
Using CLASSPATH:       /var/lib/apache-tomcat-7.0.72/bin/bootstrap.jar:/var/lib/apache-tomcat-7.0.72/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
Tomcat started.
```

Comment: If you look in the catalina.log do you see Tomcat being shutdown? You'll also need to give Tomcat a non-numerical PID so jenkins doesn't shut it down after the job finishes.
https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/ProcessTreeKiller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I founded what was the problem. Jenkins is killing processes which were started in the job. To turn it off I typed "export BUILD_ID=dontKillMe" at the start of the shell script.